# Python and Youtube Api

Tags: python, api, youtube-api, python-requests

I am trying to download data in a JSON format from youtube, via their API. I have setup my python code as such:

```
import requests 
response = requests.get(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet%2C+replies&maxResults=25&textFormat=plainText&videoId=ufGlBv8Z3NU&key={YOUR_API_KEY})
response.status_code
```

I am getting a 400 response error code. Basically, I am trying to follow the approach found here:[Youtube Try-It](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#try-it)

Parameters:

Part:snippet,replies

maxResults:25

textFormat:plainText

videoId:ufGlBv8Z3NU

Am I doing this all wrong? Or is there a better way to do this? My api key is a copy and paste, so I dont think there are any issues there.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It is working for me. Can you post the error message you are getting. Besides the 400 usually there is a JSON explaining the cause.

Answer (score 1):

You know what, it was a mistake on my part. I pasted the API key inside the curly braces, which gave me the error. Removing the curly braces fixed my issue. Thanks for checking!